# Install and configure Laravel on Mac OSx

Tags: php, macos, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to configure and use Laravel php framework..

I'm following this [Tutorial](http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-uber-quick-start-with-auth-guide?utm_source=nettuts&utm_medium=article&utm_content=api&utm_campaign=guest_author) to install and configure it.

At this point I read:

```
$ chmod -R 0777 app/storage
// This is simply setting your environment - bootstrap/start.php
$ find -name 'bootstrap/start.php' -print -exec sed -i 's/your-machine-name/localhost/g' {} \; # add machine-name to local env, for instance "localhost"
// MAC OSX FRIENDLY VERSION: find bootstrap -name 'start.php' -exec sed -i '' -e 's/your-machine-name/localhost/g' {} \;
```

I'm a mac OSx user and I'm not understood this command:

```
find bootstrap -name 'start.php' -exec sed -i '' -e 's/your-machine-name/localhost/g' {} \;
```

What is this?

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to look for a file within the bootstrap directory named 'start.php'. For matching files, it will replace 'your-machine-name' with 'localhost'. To break it down:

- `find` - Executes the find command
- `bootstrap` - The folder to search in
- `-name 'start.php'` - Searches for the file named 'start.php'
- `-exec` - For each file that matches the above find, execute the following:
- `sed -i '' -e` - Search and replace the following string: (`-i` modifies the file in-place, `-e` allows for multiple search/replaces if desired)
- `'s/your-machine-name/localhost/g'` - Replace 'your-machine-name' with 'localhost' throughout the whole file
- `{} \;` - Ends the find